# Why can't I set a third-party cookie in Firefox 3?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I can set first-party cookies just fine, but third-party cookies aren't being accepted by Firefox 3.6.16.

```
<?php
  setcookie('test', 'value', time() + 3600, '/', '.mydomain.edu');
  setcookie('anothertest', 'value', time() + 3600, '/', '.google.com');
  header('P3P:policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml",
  CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
?>
```

So the cookie `test=value` is being set with the proper domain.  However my attempts to set a cookie for `.google.com` are being rejected by the browser.  Note:

- I have third-party cookies enabled in the browser
- I have included a compact privacy policy
- I have used a P3P validator to ensure that my policy is valid
- I have used Tamper Data to ensure that the `P3P` header is being sent and that the
  `Set-Cookie` header contains the third-party cookie.

I'm very new to all of this, but from my reading this should be possible given the above.  I know that setting a cookie from an iframe is considered third-party as well, but the wikipedia entry implies that I should be able to set a third-party cookie via this technique as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: No modern day browser will accept cookies for a third-party site.  That goes against security.

Comment: @Frog: Wikipedia claims that they are accepted by default provided a P3P policy is issued by the server. Is this wrong?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Browser_settings

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does accept 3rd party cookies unless you have it turned off under Options->Privacy